# Discord.py random post from specific user

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a function that pulls a random embed placed in a channel by a bot and reposts the embed the channel where the function is called. I would like to extend the functionality here and allow the user to call the function with a filter for the user of their choosing -

!bestpost - selects a random embed from specific channel and posts it to the channel where the function is called

!bestpost $user - selects a random embed from a **specific** user in a specific channel and posts the embed to the channel where the function is called

My issue here is that the embeds that the bot has created are posted by the bot NOT the user so I can't check by author. However the user's name is always present in the title field of the bot-created embed.

```
@client.command()
async def bestpost(ctx, poster: Optional[str.lower]):
    channel = client.get_channel(123)
    best_posts = []

    # if poster is specified, then only pulls messages from that user
    if poster is not None:
        async for message in channel.history(limit=None):
            if poster in message.embeds[0].title:
                best_posts.append(message)

    # if poster is not specified, then pulls all messages
    else:
        async for message in channel.history(limit=None):
            best_posts.append(message)

    random_bestpost = random.choice(best_posts).embeds[0]

    await ctx.send(embed=random_bestpost)
```

Here is the most recent error it's been spitting at me

```
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

I've been dinking with this for a few hours and I'm pretty confident I'm just misunderstanding something simple or or just developing brain lesions from staring at such a simple problem for so long. I appreciate any feedback or assistance anyone can provide.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple solution for the thing that you want to achieve:

```
import discord 
import random 
import re 
def bestpost(user, channel): 
    all_posts = [] 
    for post in channel.history(limit=1000): 
        if user in post.title: 
            all_posts.append(post) 
    if all_posts: 
        return random.choice(all_posts)
```

##### Async Solution

I wrote a solution for you that uses the content of the message title to decide which user to filter by. If a message title has the text `$user` in it, it means you want to filter the posts by that user.
Feel free to ask for clarifications in the comments.

```
import discord
import random

TOKEN = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!bestpost'):
        args = message.content.split()

        if len(args) &gt;= 1:
            user = args[1]
        else:
            # Here you can handle the error of not specifying a user
            continue

        # This line gets all the messages from the channel
        async for message in message.channel.history():
            # This line checks if the author of the message is the bot. You can replace this condition with any other condition you like to filter the messages by.
            if message.author.id != client.user.id:
                continue

            if user in message.title:
                # This line gets the embeds from all the messages
                embeds = message.embeds

                # This line checks if there are any embeds in the message. You can replace this condition with any other condition you like to filter the messages by.
                if embeds:
                    # This line gets a random embed from the message
                    embed = random.choice(embeds)

                    # This line sends the embed to the channel where the command was used
                    await message.channel.send(embed=embed)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: I don't think it's quite correct, but I'm going to spend some time messing with your code to see if I can get the behavior I want.

The channel we want to scrape the history of is not the same channel that we want to be using the bot in. Additionally, it's always the same channel ID.

The author of every embed in that specific channel is always a bot so I want to be searching the content of the embed, which I'm not sure how to do.

Either way, I'm going to dig into this a bit once I get some more free time. Thank you for taking the time to write it all up!